# При редактировании в течение grace period'а нельзя изменить описание правки

Tags: дефект, правки

Невозможно отредактировать описание правки во время grace period'а. Поазывается, что сохранение выполнено, но реально описание остаётся старое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отредактировать описание можно, если одновременно изменить текст вопроса/ответа - например, добавить или убрать пробел в конце текста. (Или сначала добавить, а потом убрать, если хочется совсем не оставлять следов.)

Это известный дефект, с 2011 года - [Let me add or change edit summary during edit window (grace period)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79180) 
- так что устранение в ближайшие 5 лет маловероятно.